# Connection refused: spark.example.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077 when trying to connect to remote Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark, aws-security-group, connection-refused

I have a Spark Standalone Cluster setup on EC2 machine. The cluster contains a total of 1 Master and 2 Worker Nodes. When I try to submit a Spark job from a local machine to the remote master with the help of PySpark shell I get connection refused error.

On my local Machine trying to connect to remote Spark Master ( EC2 Instance ):

```
pyspark --master spark://spark.example.com:7077
```

On running the above command on local machine I get the following error:

```
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: test.example.com/52.66.70.6:7077
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 more
2018-08-31 08:58:09 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend:70 - Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
2018-08-31 08:58:09 WARN  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:66 - Application ID is not initialized yet.
2018-08-31 08:58:09 WARN  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:66 - Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
2018-08-31 08:58:09 WARN  MetricsSystem:66 - Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
2018-08-31 08:58:10 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
```

When I run the same command by logging in to one of my Spark Node, It is successfully getting connected.

/etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 spark.example.com #Changing this to floating/Public IP throws "Cannot Bind to port 7077" error
127.0.0.1 slave1
```

spark-env.sh

```
MASTER_HOST=spark.example.com
```

The EC2 Inbound security group is configured to allow "ALL Traffic" to "ALL Ports" from "Anywhere on the Internet"

Below is `lsof` log on my Spark Master node ( EC2 Instance )

```
lsof -i :7077
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    20671 ubuntu  237u  IPv6  79763      0t0  TCP localhost:7077 (LISTEN)
java    20671 ubuntu  249u  IPv6  80993      0t0  TCP localhost:7077->localhost:42553 (ESTABLISHED)
java    20671 ubuntu  250u  IPv6  80994      0t0  TCP localhost:7077->localhost:42554 (ESTABLISHED)
java    20910 ubuntu  252u  IPv6  80992      0t0  TCP localhost:42554->localhost:7077 (ESTABLISHED)
java    20912 ubuntu  251u  IPv6  80991      0t0  TCP localhost:42553->localhost:7077 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your Spark submit process cannot talk to the Spark master. You did not mention your security group configuration, and I am assuming that this is the problem.

When I configure my inbound security rules for Spark on EC2, I open all ports (TCP and UDP) but set the source to be my systems's public IP address. This means that only computers on my network can access the system.

If you want to tighten up security enable the following ports:

8080 - Spark UI

4040 - Spark Work UI

8088 - sparklr UI

7077 - Spark submit interface

Note: You need to enable all ports in your security group between the Master and the Slaves. They need to be able to openly communicate with each other.

Comment: The security configurations are already set right. The issue was with the master-slave IP addresses in the `/etc/hosts` file. I had to add the Private IP addresses of master and slave nodes instead of EC2 public IP address in the /etc/hosts file. This fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, I have private IPs in /etc/hosts and security configuration allows all traffic from all ports for the security group of the instances. Still, I am facing a connection refused from the master to the slaves. telnet from master to slave on 7077 does not work either.

Comment: To troubleshoot this connection refused error, we have to check our hosts (/etc/hosts) in the worker node. If the worker node hostname is configured with the IP 127.0.1.1, just remove that line from the /etc/hosts file.